# Get rid of "quit anyway" prompt using GDB: Just kill the process and quit

Tags: gdb

Consider:

```
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 9018] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

What is a `.gdbinit` option to make GDB always kill the running process at a quit request?

I know that GDB can attach to already-running processes, so it would be bad to kill them at quit. But for a processes started from it, a need to confirm your actions starts to annoy at a second quit.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Turning confirmation prompts off globally disabled many other useful checks, such as the one to ask you if you really want to delete all breakpoints when you type "delete".

It would be better to disable the prompt only for the quit command.  You can do that by adding this hook to your ~/.gdbinit (for current user) or /etc/gdb/gdbinit (for all users):

```
define hook-quit
    set confirm off
end
```

Comment: This can be done for any command (but not aliases), documentation is available at https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html `define hookpost-handle set confirm on end` could then also be useful to reverse the confirmation request after a command is handled.

Comment: is there something similar for lldb?

Comment: It would be great to set this via the command line (via `-ex`) but unfortunately I think this is impossible without an intermediate file (e.g., `$HOME/.gdbinit` or via `--command somefile`).

Answer (score 39):

```
set confirm off
```

See [gdb doc](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Messages_002fWarnings) for details

Comment: This does the job, but it also disables all other confirmations.

Comment: I [didn't need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631484/gdb-doesnt-support-dwarf-5-macro-sections) to interact with `gdb`, so this worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to define a new command that quits without asking for confirmation:

```
define qquit
  set confirm off
  quit
end
document qquit
Quit without asking for confirmation.
end
```

Now you can use `qquit` or just `qq` to exit quickly, without changing the default behaviour of `quit`

Comment: Nice hint, even though it interprets the question a bit liberally. :)

Answer (score 13):

In conclusion this will run the program directly and don't ask for quit confirmation:

```sh
gdb -ex="set confirm off" -ex=r --args ...
```

Answer (score -4):

**Type：*`Ctrl + D`***

**Before**

xx@yy: ~>

> (gdb)

**After**

> (gdb) quit

**Then**

xx@yy: ~>

Comment: Your answer is very vague and does not help in solving the problem at hand.

Comment: nice. this also works on lldb