# GDB disable (y or n) prompts

Tags: gdb

Is there a way to stop gdb from displaying `(y or n)` prompts all the time?

**Example:**

```
(gdb) k
Kill the program being debugged? (y or n)
```

Help doesn't show anything

```
(gdb) help kill
Kill execution of program being debugged.

List of kill subcommands:

kill inferiors -- Kill inferior ID (or list of IDs)

Type "help kill" followed by kill subcommand name for full documentation.
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Command name abbreviations are allowed if unambiguous.
```

apropos doesn't help either

```
(gdb) apropos kill
kill -- Kill execution of program being debugged
kill inferiors -- Kill inferior ID (or list of IDs)
set remote kill-packet -- Set use of remote protocol `vKill' (kill) packet
show remote kill-packet -- Show current use of remote protocol `vKill' (kill) packet`
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355978/get-rid-of-quit-anyway-question-just-kill-the-process-and-quit

Comment: @scottt thanks, that question's title isn't very search friendly.